# Hide html if metabox is empty, using custom post types

Tags: wordpress, hide, display, meta-boxes

I am trying to only show the `#firstimg` if the metabox is filled, because else it just displays an empty box because it's searching for an image that isn't there.

I am using `Custom Post Types` and I can get the images to show so far, but as soon as I try to hide the `#firstimg` all it does is mess up my code (it does not display the rest of the website, and there is nothing in my console log either so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong).

I'm assuming I might be close (hopefully?) but that I didn't write the code correctly. Hopefully someone is willing to help me out!

```
  <img class="port-img" id="firstimg" src="
  <?php $key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_img_1', true); 
    if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) { 
    echo $key_1_value; 
    document.getElementById("firstimg").style.display = "block";}
  ?>">
  <img class="port-img" id="secondimg" src="<?php $key_2_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_img_2', true); if( ! empty( $key_2_value ) ) { echo $key_2_value;}?>">
  <img class="port-img" id="thirdimg" src="<?php $key_3_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_img_3', true); if( ! empty( $key_3_value ) ) { echo $key_3_value;}?>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not escaping or echoing your JavaScript, which is what's causing the site to fail to load past that point (you're getting a Fatal Error).

Why don't you just prevent displaying the image at all if the key doesn't exist, something like this:

```
$key_1_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ecpt_img_1', true );
$key_2_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ecpt_img_2', true );
$key_3_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ecpt_img_3', true );

if( $key_1_value ) echo '<img class="port-img" id="firstimage" src="'. $key_1_value .'" />';
if( $key_2_value ) echo '<img class="port-img" id="secondimage" src="'. $key_2_value .'" />';
if( $key_3_value ) echo '<img class="port-img" id="thirdimage" src="'. $key_3_value .'" />';
```

Or better yet you could even just loop through 1, 2, and 3 as an array (note that you'd have to change your CSS from `#firstmage` to `#image-1`, etc - but it really simplifies things. You also don't need to define the key variable and then check it later, because [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) will return a *truthy* value, or `false` if it doesn't exist, so you can compare it at the same time you define it:

```
foreach( range(1,3) as $i ){
    if( $image_src = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "ecpt_img_$i", true ) ){
        echo "<img class='port-image' id='image-$i' src='$image_src' />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested them both (and obviously they work perfectly fine), and I really liked the second one. I wanted something like that but my knowledge is still lacking to write it myself. Thank you for taking the time to help me out, I very much appreciate it. :)

Comment: My pleasure, I'm happy to help - glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have javascript in your php. Maybe try something like this? I'm assuming your css doesn't have `display: none` on .port-img or #firstimg...

```
<?php $key_1_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_img_1', true); 
if( !empty( $key_1_value ) ) : ?>  
   <img class="port-img" id="firstimg" src="<?php echo $key_1_value; ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
<img class="port-img" id="secondimg" src="<?php $key_2_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_img_2', true); if( ! empty( $key_2_value ) ) { echo $key_2_value;}?>">
<img class="port-img" id="thirdimg" src="<?php $key_3_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ecpt_img_3', true); if( ! empty( $key_3_value ) ) { echo $key_3_value;}?>">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out! I tested it out and it worked :) Though I am going to use the second option Xhynk gave, as it's both clean and short, I really appreciate your help as well.